# URL.openstream not working when URL starts with "file://"

Tags: java, url

The following code is throwing the exception below:

```
URL u = new URL("file://D:/abc.xml");
InputStream input = u.openStream();
```

Exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: D
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.openServer(NetworkClient.java:118)
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:488)
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:475)
at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:270)
at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:352)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at com.nuance.nlu.JavaApiExmaple.main(Exmaple.java:191)
ERROR: JDWP Unable to get JNI 1.2 environment, jvm->GetEnv() return code = -2
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_NO_JNI_ENV(183):  [../../../src/share/back/util.c:820]
```

However if I use:

- `URL u = new URL("file:///D:/abc.xml");` (3 slashes after file), or:
- `URL u = new URL("file:/D:/abc.xml");` (1 slash after file:)

the line of code `InputStream input = u.openStream();`  executes fine.

Comment: Let's see - use the first one....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First see: [What is the reason that file URLs start with three slashes: “file:///” etc?](https://superuser.com/questions/352133) for a detailed description.

Excerpt from that answer:

> The complete syntax is `file://host/path`.
>
> If the host is `localhost`, it can be omitted, resulting in `file:///path`.

Comment: So shall I say that using "file://D:/abc.xml" the part "D:" is interpeted as the name of the host .....right ?

Comment: Another question arises in my mind is  why does a single slash work?